# Using Slow Cheetah to transform Nuspec files

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, slowcheetah, nuspec

I have used [Slow Cheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) in the past to transform various `.config` and `.xml` files, but now I'd like use it transform a `.nuspec` file. However, the 'Add Transform' doesn't appear when I right-click on the file. I'm fairly sure that this is just because Slow Cheetah doesn't know anything about the `.nuspec` file extension.

Is there a way to configure Slow Cheetah so that it can transform Nuspec files, or for that matter, any file extension I need it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was not that the file I wanted to transform was a `.nuspec` file, but that it was not in any project. The Slow Cheetah extensions are applied on a per-project basis, but my `.nuspec` file was simply added to as an item to the solution.

Once I added it to a project, the 'Add Transform' option appeared. It seems that adding it to any project would've worked, but I'm currently using the [NuGet Packager](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/daf5c6db-386b-4994-bdd7-b6cd52f11b72) project template.